# show previous component till next component get loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-loadable

i am using react-loadable to load the component when required but in react-loadable we have to show some loading component till the component get loaded in background but i want to show previous component till the next component get loaded. Please help me with this issue.
Note - i am doing route based code splitting using webpack.

Comment: so, how about showing the code you have till now?

Comment: yes i want to show the component from which new route is triggered till the next component bundle get loaded but how??

Comment: You can't because you have already entered that route and the promise is being resolved at that time...

Comment: Check https://www.hackerrank.com/dashboard they are doing route based routing and when we navigate from practice to contest section previous component remains there till next component get loaded.